# XNA Scale texture to predefined values

Tags: c#, .net, windows, xna

I'm trying to move a texture towards a fixed point. That works fine, but the texture, I use, hasn't got the right size anymore.

```
spriteBatch.Draw(plane.texture, new Vector2(plane.posX, plane.posY), null, Color.White, plane.rotation, new Vector2(plane.width / 2, plane.height / 2), new Vector2((float)0.2, (float)0.2), SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

I know how to resize the texture by float values, but the texture has to have a size of 40x40..

Any Ideas how to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Well, either use The ZMan's solution, or instead of drawing with a Vector2, use a rectangle. That way you specify its Width and Height :P With this case, you'd of course be assuming that the scale is 1x1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the texture to always be 40, 40 then your scale factor should be this

```
new Vector2(40f/plane.Texture.Width, 40f/plane.Texture.Height)
```

Otherwise you need to explain exactly what it is you are trying to do.